# Regex - find matches not contained within pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to use a regular expression to match all occurrences of a phrase where it's not contained within some delimiting characters. I tried putting one together but had some difficulty with the negative lookaheads.

My search phrase is "my phrase". The start delimiter tag is [[ and the end delimiter tag is ]]. The string I'd like to search is:

Here is a sentence with *my phrase*, here's another part which I don't want to match on [[my phrase]]. I would like to find this occurrence of *my phrase*.

From this string I would expect to find all occurrences of "my phrase" except the one contained within [[ ]].

I hope that makes sense, thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Please share your regex. You most probably need to adapt the code for the pattern, and lookarounds are most probably not necessary here. When you need to match something except when in-between some delimiters, it almost always means matching the delimited substrings, and then match what you need in other contexts while capturing in either of them. What is your final goal? Just extract `my phrase`s from the expected contexts?

Comment: Are you looiking for, say `source.IndexOf("[[my phrase]]")`, or `source.Replace("[[my phrase]]", "myPhraseSubstitution");`?

Comment: I'm looking for all occurrences of "my phrase" where they're not contained within [[ ]]. With the matches I will then transform the string.

Comment: @squariegoes So, you need to *replace* `my phrase` not in-between `[[` and `]]`. Use [`var my_res = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?s)(\[\[.*?]])|my phrase", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : "NEW_STR");`](https://ideone.com/jCKJvJ).

Answer (score 1):

`[^#]my phrase[^#]`

I have knocked up a RegEx that will do what you ask, this can be seen [here](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=99028).

Literally just escaping out `#` as a character and allowing any other character to be returned. You can return the index of these results but remember to strip off the first and last character of the string.

**Note: This will not pick up any "my phrase" that end the sentence without a character following it**

***Edit - Seeing as you changed the scope while I was writing this answer,
 here is the RegEx for the other delimiter:***

`[^[[]my phrase[^\]\]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=[^\[])my phrase(?=[^\]]*)
```

This will also elliminate the trailing punctuation marks.

Comment: `(?<=[^\[])my phrase(?=[^\]]*)` will not match `my phrase` at the start/end of the string due to the negated character classes that must match a char other than the char(s) defined in them.

Comment: It sort of will match if the pattern is at the end - * allows for 0 or more occurances. But yes, to match at it at the start as well, this is better:
`(?<=[^\[])my phrase(?=[^\]]*)|^my phrase(?=[^\]]*)`

Comment: Thanks, this helped